# Vue 'computed' filters

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-component

Is it possible to pull in a variable from a filter, and have the filter update when this changes? Like it does in a computed property?

I'm wanting to be able to do something like:

```
Vue.filter('t', function(val) {
    return this.currentLanguage[val];
});
```

and have the filter recompile the template when `this.currentLanguage` changes.

Obviously I can pass in an additional parameter, but I don't want to have to do this for each string.

My code works when switching components, so alternatively, is there a way to force a recompile? I'm using `vue-router`, but

```
this.$route.router.go({
    path: this.$route.router.path,
        query: {
            t: + new Date()
         }
    })
}
```

unfortunately doesn't trigger a recompile.

Comment: Could you explain the problem in greater depth? I made a [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/asemahle/qzuyxqq7/) where the filter depends on an external variable. It works without issue.

Comment: Ah right, I see. I think my issue is that I'm using my translator as a plugin, with `Vue.use(Translator)`. Therefore, in my translator, the `this.currentLanguage` isn't being observed, as it is just a plain property of an object, rather than in the Vue data.

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you provided runnable code that demonstrated this behavior. [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) type stuff is always great

Answer (score 0):

You could define reactivity by using:

```
Vue.util.defineReactive(obj, key, val)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pespantelis/qzuyxqq7/3/

Also, I have created a package for that:

https://github.com/pespantelis/vue-localizer